# In Applesoft BASIC, does combining statements into a single line speed up execution?

Tags: apple-ii, applesoft-basic

In Applesoft BASIC, does combining statements into a single line speed up execution?

For example, would this:

```
10 PRINT "HELLO WORLD" : FOR I = 1 TO 100 : PRINT I : NEXT I
```

Run faster than this:

```
10 PRINT "HELLO WORLD"
20 FOR I = 1 to 100
30 PRINT I
40 NEXT I
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

---

Handling line end and a new lines start does take more time for the interpreter than skiping a colon.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Replacing `NEXT I` with `NEXT` will also help.

One way to evaluate this is to throw a speaker click (`PEEK -16336`) into the loop and listen.  The faster the loop, the higher the pitch.  (Then try it with `SP=-16336` outside the loop and `PEEK SP` in the loop, and note the effect that has...)

Comment: Counterintuitively, on Commodore BASIC, "NEXT" is faster than "NEXT I".  "NEXT" simply pops off the most recently nested FOR variable; "NEXT I" has to do pull I off the stack and then push back any more recent FOR loops (which can create some program execution fun).